# amazon EMR spark-submit doesn't allow docker Image pattern sha256 diges

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am using Amazon EMR

my question log is following.

```
Image name '<account_id>.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/pyspark-etl@sha256:3d3a07135.......https://forums.aws.amazon.com/....0.87563e51ef5c841841a5d1a6dde9c' doesn't match docker image name pattern
```

Release label:emr-6.2.0 
Hadoop distribution:Amazon 3.2.1 
Applications:Spark 3.0.1, 
Hive 3.1.2, 
JupyterHub 1.1.0, 
Ganglia 3.7.2 
Zeppelin 0.9.0 
Livy 0.7.0 \
Hue 4.8.0 
PrestoSQL 343

The reason I had to use sha256 digest is becuase I previously used TAG:latest pyspark image hardcoded in airflow job ALSO containerized in ECR image.
so, when my airflow container runs a EMROperator(SSHoperator precisely) as a CLI spark-submit. It pull :latest spark container which doesn't update because of some reason.

It is strange because when I ssh into core instance, I am able to pull sha256 name pattern from ECR, also update :latest TAG if something is changed(so digest changed).

I think this is something about **spark configuration** or **spark source from AWS** which prohibited digest name pattern, but I can't debug this because I do not have spark(Amazon) source on my own. I would appreciate your answer.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am editing on my own because I got an answer from someone.
The problem was YARN configuration installed on my EMR master node. YARN default setting for docker default image update is False.

https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/03cfc852791c14fad39db4e5b14104a276c08e59/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/nodemanager/containermanager/linux/runtime/DockerLinuxContainerRuntime.java#L344
[image]

so, in order to fix default setting, you should go `/etc/hadoop/conf/` and find a `yarn-sites.xml` and fix(or add) this

```
<property>

<name>yarn.nodemanager.runtime.linux.docker.image-update</name>

<value>false</value>

<description>

Optional. Default option to decide whether to pull the latest image

or not.

</description>

</property>
```

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/DockerContainers.html